# Create matrix with mismatched vectors

Tags: matlab, matrix

How can I enter a matrix composed of mismatched vectors such that the missing values are filled with zeros `0` or not a number `NaN`?

(Obviously, a matrix of zeros can be created first, and mismatching vectors can be added line by line, but what if I want to 1-line this?)

**Example:**

How can I enter a matrix such as:

```
a = [
      1   2   3   4;
      1   2        ; 
      1            ;
    ];
```

which results in:

```
a = [
      1   2   3   4;
      1   2   0   0; 
      1   0   0   0;
    ];
```

or

```
c = [
      1   2   3   4;
      1   2 NaN NaN; 
      1 NaN NaN NaN;
    ];
```

**Undesired Solution:**

```
a        = zeros(3,4);
a(1,1:4) = [1 2 3 4];
a(2,1:2) = [1 2    ];
a(3,1:1) = [1      ];
```

Comment: How are those mismatched vectors stored/how are you getting those vectors?

Comment: Manual entering as shown.  Very easy for the program to process and create and handle zero pads, but for human users, they get lost in the wide array of zeros.

Comment: Also trying to avoid making a cell of vectors, although that would also a possible solution.

Comment: There are a couple of solution by Bruno Luong in this [2012 question on MATLAB Central](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/321014).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jos van der Geest submitted a popular and indeed very nice utility for this on the MathWorks File Exchange -- [`padcat`](http://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22909-padcat-varargin-).

In essence, it automates what you proposed to do manually. However, it uses some smart concatenations and indexing tricks to create said matrix very efficiently.

Here is the current version:

```
function [M, TF] = padcat(varargin)
% PADCAT - concatenate vectors with different lengths by padding with NaN
%
%   M = PADCAT(V1, V2, V3, ..., VN) concatenates the vectors V1 through VN
%   into one large matrix. All vectors should have the same orientation,
%   that is, they are all row or column vectors. The vectors do not need to
%   have the same lengths, and shorter vectors are padded with NaNs.
%   The size of M is determined by the length of the longest vector. For
%   row vectors, M will be a N-by-MaxL matrix and for column vectors, M
%   will be a MaxL-by-N matrix, where MaxL is the length of the longest 
%   vector.
%
%   Examples:
%      a = 1:5 ; b = 1:3 ; c = [] ; d = 1:4 ;
%      padcat(a,b,c,d) % row vectors
%         % ->   1     2     3     4     5
%         %      1     2     3   NaN   NaN
%         %    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
%         %      1     2     3     4   NaN
%      CC = {d.' a.' c.' b.' d.'} ;
%      padcat(CC{:}) % column vectors
%         %      1     1   NaN     1     1
%         %      2     2   NaN     2     2
%         %      3     3   NaN     3     3
%         %      4     4   NaN   NaN     4
%         %    NaN     5   NaN   NaN   NaN
%
%   [M, TF] = PADCAT(..) will also return a logical matrix TF with the same
%   size as R having true values for those positions that originate from an 
%   input vector. This may be useful if any of the vectors contain NaNs.
%
%   Example:
%       a = 1:3 ; b = [] ; c = [1 NaN] ;
%       [M,tf] = padcat(a,b,c)
%       % find the original NaN
%       [Vev,Pos] = find(tf & isnan(M))
%       % -> Vec = 3 , Pos = 2
%
%   This second output can also be used to change the padding value into
%   something else than NaN.
%
%       [M, tf] = padcat(1:3,1,1:4) 
%       M(~tf) = 99 % change the padding value into 99
%
%   Scalars will be concatenated into a single column vector.
%
%   See also CAT, RESHAPE, STRVCAT, CHAR, HORZCAT, VERTCAT, ISEMPTY
%            NONES, GROUP2CELL (Matlab File Exchange)

% for Matlab 2008 and up (tested in R2015a)
% version 2.2 (feb 2016)
% (c) Jos van der Geest
% email: samelinoa@gmail.com

% History
% 1.0 (feb 2009) created
% 1.1 (feb 2011) improved comments
% 1.2 (oct 2011) added help on changing the padding value into something
%     else than NaN
% 2.2 (feb 2016) updated contact info 

% Acknowledgements:
% Inspired by padadd.m (feb 2000) Fex ID 209 by Dave Johnson

narginchk(1,Inf) ;

% check the inputs
SZ = cellfun(@size,varargin,'UniformOutput',false) ; % sizes
Ndim = cellfun(@ndims,varargin) ; % 

if ~all(Ndim==2)
    error([mfilename ':WrongInputDimension'], ...
        'Input should be vectors.') ;
end

TF = [] ; % default second output so we do not have to check all the time

% for 2D matrices (including vectors) the size is a 1-by-2 vector
SZ = cat(1,SZ{:}) ;
maxSZ = max(SZ) ;    % probable size of the longest vector
% maxSZ equals :
%  - [1 1] for all scalars input
%  - [X 1] for column vectors
%  - [1 X] for all row vectors
%  - [X Y] otherwise (so padcat will not work!)

if ~any(maxSZ == 1),  % hmm, not all elements are 1-by-N or N-by-1
    % 2 options ...
    if any(maxSZ==0),
        % 1) all inputs are empty
        M  = [] ;
        return
    else
        % 2) wrong input 
        % Either not all vectors have the same orientation (row and column
        % vectors are being mixed) or an input is a matrix.
        error([mfilename ':WrongInputSize'], ...
            'Inputs should be all row vectors or all column vectors.') ;
    end
end

if nargin == 1,
    % single input, nothing to concatenate ..
    M = varargin{1} ;
else
    % Concatenate row vectors in a row, and column vectors in a column.
    dim = (maxSZ(1)==1) + 1 ;      % Find out the dimension to work on
    X = cat(dim, varargin{:}) ;    % make one big list

    % we will use linear indexing, which operates along columns. We apply a
    % transpose at the end if the input were row vectors.

    if maxSZ(dim) == 1,
        % if all inputs are scalars, ...
        M = X ;   % copy the list
    elseif all(SZ(:,dim)==SZ(1,dim)),
        % all vectors have the same length
        M = reshape(X,SZ(1,dim),[]) ;% copy the list and reshape
    else
        % We do have vectors of different lengths.
        % Pre-allocate the final output array as a column oriented array. We
        % make it one larger to accommodate the largest vector as well.
        M = zeros([maxSZ(dim)+1 nargin]) ;
        % where do the fillers begin in each column
        M(sub2ind(size(M), SZ(:,dim).'+1, 1:nargin)) = 1 ;
        % Fillers should be put in after that position as well, so applying
        % cumsum on the columns
        % Note that we remove the last row; the largest vector will fill an
        % entire column.
        M = cumsum(M(1:end-1,:),1) ; % remove last row

        % If we need to return position of the non-fillers we will get them
        % now. We cannot do it afterwards, since NaNs may be present in the
        % inputs.
        if nargout>1,
            TF = ~M ;
            % and make use of this logical array
            M(~TF) = NaN ; % put the fillers in
            M(TF)  = X ;   % put the values in
        else
            M(M==1) = NaN ; % put the fillers in
            M(M==0) = X ;   % put the values in
        end
    end

    if dim == 2,
        % the inputs were row vectors, so transpose
        M = M.' ;
        TF = TF.' ; % was initialized as empty if not requested
    end
end % nargin == 1

if nargout > 1 && isempty(TF),
    % in this case, the inputs were all empty, all scalars, or all had the
    % same size.
    TF = true(size(M)) ;
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution if you have only digits (0-9). The input is a list of characters, separated with one space or comma for a new elements, and `;` for a new line:

```
str = '1,2 3 4;1,2;1;';
arr = strsplit(str,';');
M = char(arr)-'0';
M(M<0) = 0;
M(:,sum(M)==0)=[]
```

Note, that if you use R2016b then [`split`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/split.html) is [recommended](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html#moreabout) instead of [`strsplit`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html)

The result:

M =

```
 1     2     3     4
 1     2     0     0
 1     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0
```

And this is a version for numbers with more than one digit. Here the elemnts must be saparetad with one comma:

```
str = '1,12,300,4;1,23,3;1';
elem = str2num(char(strsplit(str,',')));
arr = char(strsplit(str,';'));
out = [ones(3,1) arr==','];
out(:,sum(out)==0) = [];
out = out.';
out(out==1) = elem;
out = out.'
```

the result:

```
out =
     1    12   300     4
     1    23     3     0
     1     0     0     0
```

Comment: `split` in matlab is listed as a calendar function. do you know its matlab equivalent?

Comment: @kando [`split`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/split.html) is a builtin since R2014b. [`strsplit`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html) is similar to it in functionality.

Comment: seems that you're right. in my 2015b installation, `help split` gives me `help calendarDuration/split`. doesn't seem to be an issue in 2016b installation..